# mod_rewrite on wamp doesn't work, RewriteBase shut the server

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to use mod_rewrite on wamp for some caching purpose.

I deleted # from the line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`,

I added the code below at the bottom of httpd.conf in Apache,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(js|css)/(.+)\.(.+)\.(js|css)$ $1/$2.$4 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

but it didn't work.
When I also added `RewriteBase /mysite/` below `RewriteEngine on`, and restarted, the server doesn't work, doesn't turn green, stays orange.
Apache error logs say

```
[Sun May 07 12:37:22.857184 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5940:tid 660] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun May 07 12:37:24.888455 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2656:tid 588] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun May 07 12:37:25.013437 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5940:tid 660] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2656 exited successfully.
```

I changed all `AllowOverride None` codes to `AllowOverride All`, but it didn't effect.

What can the problem be?

Comment: Did you restart your server without the `RewriteBase` rule?

Comment: @gaganshera Yes, I had restarted.
I tried one more time by restarting, but doesn't work.

Comment: Did you restart it before you put in the `RewriteBase` rule?

Comment: Yes, I had done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way for anyone to determine whether this should work or not is if we know the URL you are requesting. However ...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(js|css)/(.+)\.(.+)\.(js|css)$ $1/$2.$4 [NC,L]
> ```

In a *server context* (as opposed to a *directory* context like `.htaccess`) then the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the full URL-path, which notably starts with a slash. So, this `RewriteRule` will never match in a server context. The regex needs to start `^/(js|css)`. (The regex also looks a bit ambiguous if the requested URL contained more than two dots.

> When I also added `RewriteBase /mysite/` below `RewriteEngine on`, and restarted, the server doesn't work

The `RewriteBase` directive applies only in a *directory* context. In a server (or virtual host) context it is meaningless since all URLs are rewritten relative to the document root. And if you try to use `RewriteBase` here then Apache will indeed fail to start (with a rather non-specific error).

Comment: Thank you, I got the point.
I will study more on regex, and I will share the result.

Comment: You're welcome. If this sort of answered your question then please mark it accepted (checkmark on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Much appreciated, thanks. :)

Comment: Solved. I changed my structure by starting to use virtual hosts. I decided to use htaccess instead of httpd.conf.